# JavaScript Help! Stop Alert Box from resetting form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to stop the javascript from clearing the form text input by the user. Here is my function. It is set to loop until it exits, and works like I need it too. Now I need it not delete the data in the text boxes as I need it to run a second function from a different button.

```
function formValidate () {
    var validateName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var validateAge = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var validateEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var validateWeight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var validateHeight = document.getElementById("height").value;

    var x=document.forms["form3"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (validateName == null || validateName=="")
    {
    alert("First name must be filled out." + '\n' + "Please fill out again.");
    return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(validateAge) || validateAge==null || validateAge=="")
    {
    alert("Age must be filled out and/or be numeric." + '\n' + "Please fill out again.");
    return false;
    }

    else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
    {
    alert("Email must be in a valid email address format." + '\n' + "Please fill out again.");
    return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(validateWeight) || validateWeight==null || validateWeight=="")
    {
    alert("Weight must be filled out and/or be numeric." + '\n' + "Please fill out again.");
    return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(validateHeight) || validateHeight==null || validateHeight=="")
    {
    alert("Height must be filled out and/or be numeric" + '\n' + "Please fill out again.");
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this function... what exactly is the problem? It might be with your other code. How does the loop work you are talking about? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. Unless you provide more information, I don't think we can help you.

Comment: No where in that function does it clear the text in the inputs.

Comment: Is the function called `onsubmit`, and does the form then submit to the same page URL effectively reloading the form with no values? Show (at least some of) the html for your form element, and how the function is called.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `<form ... onsubmit="return formValidate ()" ...>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional information on your HTML, I'm guessing that your function is called when the user clicks on an input element, type='submit'?

And that this then causes the browser to execute the submit action clearing your form.

I think the most painless way to solve this is to use a regular button element instead, that way you have more control about how it handles the form. You can then have your function callback to a submit action.

Comment: Or it's triggered on a reset button :P

Comment: Or perhaps using event prevent default method?

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Great suggestion, I'm not sure if he's using jquery, if not I recommend that he does

Comment: @xlm—jQuery won't fix faulty logic. It may be that the OP is using a BUTTON element in a form. Buttons are, by default, submit buttons.

Comment: My problem was the button was type="submit". I changed it to type="button" and it all works. Thanks for the quick reply!